# Why is the number randomNumber function running when I enter a number into the box and select Guess

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a homework assignment to create a hot/cold app but have become stuck on the submit (Guess) button. I wrote a function called newGame so when you select New Game the randomNumberGenerator function will run. But it appears that it is also running if you enter a number into the input box and choose the Guess button but I am not sure why. Here is my script below, as well as a link to a js fiddle with the entire code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var randomNumber = 0;
var userGuess = 0;
var guessCount = 0;

//generates number
function randomNumberGenerator() {
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.floor(Math.random()*100));
    console.log("random number= " + randomNumber);
}

randomNumberGenerator();
//starts new game
function newGame(){
    guessCount = 0;
    randomNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random()*100));
    console.log("new number is " + randomNumber);
}

function compareGuess(){
    if (userGuess == randomNumber) {
    $('#feedack').text('correct');
    }
}

//submit
$('#guessButton').click(function() {
    compareGuess();
});

//click for new game
$( ".new" ).click(function() {
newGame();
});


});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w8jxqjem/1/

Thank you for your help, I am a beginner. Please let me know if there is any other information that I can provide.

Comment: It runs on `DOM` ready. I can get `console` on New Game.

Comment: Change button `type` `submit` to `button`.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent it from running the randomNumberGenerator function when Guess is selected. The user will need to be able to make multiple guesses without the random number changing.

Comment: Please check updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w8jxqjem/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Button type `submit` to `button`

```
<input type="button" id="guessButton" class="button" name="submit" value="Guess"/>
```

**JS**

```
function compareGuess(){
        //changes made here
        //if (userGuess == randomNumber) {   
        if ($("#userGuess").val() == randomNumber) {
        //you have miss spelled "feedback"
        $('#feedback').text('correct');
        }
    }
```

Also on New Game you have to reset all things but you can do `window.location.reload()` on New Game `click`.

[Check Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w8jxqjem/5/)

Answer (score 0):

`randomNumberGenerator` is not running when Guess is clicked.

The page is reloading, because an `input` with type `submit` will tries to submit a form (which reloads the page).

You are misunderstanding some semantics between `button` and `submit`. They are similar, but `button` does not refresh the page in this case, and `submit` does.

So when Guess is clicked, the page reloads, and `randomNumberGenerator` runs. But this only happens because the page refreshed, not because Guess was clicked.

To fix this, you need to change the `input` type to `button` instead of `submit`.